# Jquery, using $.each, doesn't get the value of variable

Tags: jquery, html-select, addition, each

I'm using Jquery to add some options to a select, but, the options are not always the same, so, I use a variable called materia to get the value of a previus select to know which options I should add.
I dont know if Im explaining correctly, here's some code.

...

```
materia = $("#selMateria").val();
```

...

```
$.each(materia, function(val,text){
    $("#selGrupo").append(new Option(text,val));
});
```

I had previously defined variables with the names of the values I can get

```
var name{
    opt : 'text'
}
```

The problem is that despite I get the correct value on var materia, the function that adds the option doesn't work.

If someone wants to see the entire code:

**INDEX.php**:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-centered form-group">
    <label for="facultad">Facultad</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="facultad" id="selFac" required>
        <option selected disabled hidden value="">---</option>
        <option value="ingenieria">Ingeniería</option>
        <option value="economia">Economía</option>
        <option value="derecho">Derecho</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-centered form-group" id="divMateria">
    <label for="materia">Materia</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="materia" id="selMateria" required>
        <option selected disabled hidden value="">---</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-centered form-group" id="divGrupo">
    <label for="grupo">Grupo</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="grupo" id="selGrupo" required>
        <option selected disabled hidden value="">---</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

AND HERE'S THE JQUERY FUNCTION

```
function addOpt(id, tipo, optDe) {
    removeAllSel(id);
    if (tipo == 'mat') {
        switch (optDe)
        {
            case 'ingenieria':
                $.each(matIng, function(val, text) {
                    $("#" + id).append(new Option(text, val));
                });
                break;
            case 'economia':
                $.each(matEco, function(val, text) {
                    $("#" + id).append(new Option(text, val));
                });
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (tipo == 'gru') {
        materia = $("#selMateria").val();
        $("#" + id).append(new Option($("#selMateria").val(), 'val'));
        $.each(materia, function(val, text) {
            $("#selGrupo").append(new Option(text, val));
        });
    }
    else {
        removeAllSel(id);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey mate, can you, please, post more of your code? That's not enough to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
materia = $("#selMateria").val();
$("#" + id).append(new Option($("#selMateria").val(), 'val'));
$.each(materia, function(val, text) {
    $("#selGrupo").append(new Option(text, val));
});
```

In this case `materia` contains single value of select. `$.each` in this case will iterate only on that single value. I assume that you wanted something like:

```
materia = $("#selMateria").val();
$("#" + id).append(new Option($("#selMateria").val(), 'val'));
$.each($("#selMateria"), function(val, text) {
    $("#selGrupo").append(new Option(text, val));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With $.each I want to iterate with a variable called the same name as $("#selMateria").val()

Comment: As you can see on [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), `$.each` needs an array as first argument. In your actual code `.val()` is returning `""`, as your `<option selected disabled hidden value="">---</option>` has undefined value.

Comment: Ok, I definetly need to read more of the documentation, lol. Thank you Paul !

Comment: If you can clearly explain your business logic, we'll try to help you. What should your code do? What do you want it to do when interacting with it?